# Convert a string from UART to hex value in c

Tags: microcontroller, pic, uart

I am working on pic controllers. I have a string "040F" which is sent to the controller through UART.

I want to convert this string to a hex representation such as 0x040F. I tried a code snippet but no success.

Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: What code snippet did you try? What were the errors? The more relevant information you provide the easier it will be for other users to help you.

Comment: Please post the code that didn't work. There is no point posting that *does* work ;)

Comment: Hex format is a textual representation, which you already have. If you mean to convert it to a numeric value, you can try `sscanf` or `strtol`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is to convert a hex string to binary, the below code can help. It may not be an optimized one and may be other simpler solutions are available in the internet and can be even buggy. But it will give you some idea, I hope.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_STR_LEN     16
int hex_char_to_bin(char ch)
{
        if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
                return (ch - '0');
        }
        else if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        {
                return (10 + ch - 'a');
        }
        else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        {
                return (10 + ch - 'A');
        }
        return -1;
}
int hex_str_to_bin(const char *hex_str, int *result)
{
        int str_len, i;
        int bin_val = 0;
        str_len = strnlen(hex_str, MAX_STR_LEN);
        for (i = 0; i < str_len; i++)
        {
                int val = hex_char_to_bin(*hex_str++);
                if (val == -1)
                        return -1;

                bin_val = (bin_val<<4) + val;
        }

        *result = bin_val;
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
        char str[] = "043f";
        int hex;
        if(!hex_str_to_bin(str, &hex))
                printf("%x\n",hex);
        else
                printf("Invalid hex charecters in string\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think using `pow()` here is wrong an inefficient.  `pow()` is meant to work with `double`s.  Shifting would be a better choice... perhaps like what is shown [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/763e2a58c2dc89d8e10b).

Comment: @jszakmeister Yes, You are right. Thanks for the correction :)